# What does navbar-static-top do in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

According to the documentation of [the Bootstrap 3's navbar static-top](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-static-top),

> Static top
>   Create a full-width navbar that scrolls away with the page by adding .navbar-static-top and include a .container or .container-fluid to center and pad navbar content.
>
> Unlike the .navbar-fixed-* classes, you do not need to change any padding on the body.

what does this method do? The above documentation looks like to me that the navbar is fixed at the top of the screen even when I scroll down the page to the bottom. However, it's what `.navbar-fixed-top` does, and when I used `.navbar-fixed-top` in my app, it works exactly what I've mentioned.

However, when I wrote `.navbar-static-top` in my app, I don't know what makes it different from just the `.navbar-default`. Anyone can help me in clarifying the difference and what the `.navbar-static-top` do?

Comment: It basically cleans the borders up so that they will play nicely with 100% viewport width at the top of the viewport. Look at [with](http://www.bootply.com/129340) vs [without](http://www.bootply.com/129343).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`navbar-static-top` removes the left,right and top border created by `navbar-default` so that it looks better at the top of the page, whereas you might want to use just  `navbar-default` elsewhere on the page...

### navbar-static-top: http://bootply.com/129342

On the other hand, `navbar-fixed-top` uses `position:fixed`. If there is content on the page that extends below the viewport (as there is on most pages) the `navbar-fixed-top` will remain stuck to the top, whereas the `navbar-static-top` will scroll away. Since the `navbar-fixed-top` is fixed, it requires the body to have padding-top so that it doesn't overlay page content...

### navbar-fixed-top: http://bootply.com/129345

As you can see when you scroll down in each example the top navbar responds differently.

Comment: Thanks. Then if I put `.navbar-default` on the top of the screen with full width, then `.navbar-default` is no different from `.navbar-static-top`, right? I know what's the difference between `.navbar-static-top` and `.navbar-fixed-top`, but not sure between `.navbar-static-top` and `.navbar-default` with it being set to the top.

Comment: There is no difference with it being set to the top. The difference is with the border of the navbar. Again, `navbar-static-top` removes the left,right and top border.

Comment: I went to your first example in bootply (navbar-static-top), removed the class navbar-static-top from it, re-run the bootply, there was no visual change whatsoever.. whats going on ?!