# careousel below the navbar is blocking part of my logo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I used an image in my nav bar as a logo. The careousel below the navbar is blocking part of the logo like this. How do I bring the image to the foreground?

[image]

Here it the short version of the navbar code:

```
<!--Navigation Bar
================================================== -->
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbard-static-top">
  <div class = "container">

    <!--Logo-->
    <div class = "navbar-brand" style="color:#00E6E6" pull-left><strong>
      <img src="resources/logo-navbar.png" class="logo-navbar"/>
      <strong>
    </div>

  </div><!--End Navigation Bar Container-->
</div><!--End Navigation Bar-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your navbar class. 'navbard-static-top' should be 'navbar-static-top'. Thats the problem. :)

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020763/what-does-navbar-static-top-do-in-bootstrap-3) when I was searching for fixed navbars, so just modified it to match this answer. Correct the typo and you'll see the result.
http://www.bootply.com/BFQxiF039t

Comment: OMG thank you so much that is hilarious!