# How do I keep nav-tabs in boostrap fixed on the top while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Page in Rails which has 4-5 tabs. Each tab renders a partial (say a page). I want to be able to keep the tabs fixed on the screen at the top or some margin from the top, even though a user scrolls down. I have used Bootstrap's `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` for tabs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020763/what-does-navbar-static-top-do-in-bootstrap-3

Comment: I have already read it, and tried. The scrolling content overlaps the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media
only screen and (your condition)
{
 [class*="nav-tabs"] 
  {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: -11%; // adjust according to your need
  }
  // you are probably gonna mess up tab-content margin as well, so adjust it as I have shown below
  [class*="tab-content"] 
  {
    margin-top: 5%; // insert n% as per your need
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add class `navbar-fixed-top` to nav ul

Comment: hey, it workd, the nav-tab's tab section stays on the top, but links in navbar become inactive, or maybe the navbar itself becomes inactive.

Comment: Hi, Kinga, maybe those links should go on the answer? I'm writing this on the Low Quality Posts review, extremelly short answers end up here...

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)